# Qt QGraphicsView Event

Tags: c++, qt, events, qt-events

I have a class `View` that incorporates my `QGraphicsView` but I am having trouble inheriting from it. My code is as follows:

```
class View: public QGraphicsView {//inherits qwidget -- so we can make it full screen there

    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        View(QGraphicsScene * _scene);//this is responsible for setting up the screen and instantiating several elements
        ~View();
    protected:
        virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event) = 0;
```

And `Game` inherits from `View`:

```
#include "view.h" //this includes all of the functionality of the different elements

using namespace std;

class Game : public View {//inherit everything above and down into private functions

    public:
        Game(QGraphicsScene * _scene);
        ~Game();

    protected:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event);

};
```

I have implemented `paintEvent` with just a quick `cout` in `game`. When I compile, everything compiles okay but when I run, I keep getting a message that says a pure virtual function was called:

```
libc++abi.dylib: pure virtual method called
Abort trap: 6
```

My `View` constructor looks like this:

```
View::View(QGraphicsScene * _scene) : QGraphicsView(_scene) {...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the pure virtuality (= 0) of `paintEvent` in your base class. Since it's called from within QT i think, this would be the problem.

Comment: Can you show the call stack when you get pure virtual call?

Comment: I ended up having to implement an empty function for the paint event in the base class. Thanks for quick fix

Comment: `View::paintEvent()` should not be called by Qt, `Game::paintEvent()` should be called. Maybe you call `View::paintEvent()` in your `Game::paintEvent()` implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I got the `paintEvent` function to compile and open my application. But for some reason, whenever I try to draw on my scene, it doesn't work.

However, if I take out the `paintEvent` function, it works fine. Any suggestions as to why the `paintEvent` breaks this?

in my main file:

```
QGraphicsEllipseItem * item = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, scene);

    item->setRect(50.0, 50.0, 100.0, 100.0);

    view->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    view->show();
```

This works if I get rid of the virtual `paintEvent` function, but including it will break the circle from drawing?

Comment: You generally don't need to override `QGraphicsView::paintEvent()`, instead you implement your `QGraphicsObject::paint()` method in order to draw what you need. Try to call `QGraphicsView::paintEvent()` at the beginning of your `Game::paintEvent()` and see whether it works.

Comment: Hey, this worked. By calling QGraphicsObject::paintEvent(), Everything worked out great! Thanks